# how to use method inside method of a constructor?

Tags: javascript

```
method.getTotalDays = function(){
    return (this.longi-this.age)*365;
}

method.eatPercent = function(){
    return this.eat/24;
}
```

In my next method within this constructor, I want to calculate the days that "eating process" costs in my life. For example, I want to have a method like this:

```
method.getEatingDays = function(){
var days = 0;
days = eatPercent*totalDays; //How do I get eatPercent and totalDays by using the established  
                             //methods?
}
```

Comment: this.eat is in terms of hours.

Answer (score 2):

If the `method` is defined as an object, you can do

```
days = method.eatPercent() * method.totalDays();
```

If method is a function, then you need

```
days = this.eatPercent() * this.totalDays();
```

`this` here refers to the owner which calls `getEatingDays()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call those getter function in the current instance, this can be done via `this.fnName()`

```
method.getEatingDays = function(){
var days = 0;
days = this.eatPercent()*this.getTotalDays();
}
```